# How to create a visual scale for resume?

Tags: cv

In LaTeX, I am trying to scale my skills visually for my resume. So it should be something like this:

[image: Skills]

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to do this figure in LaTeX? Try `tikz`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for your answer and comment. I hope my format here wasn't too bad. I will check and try your answer as soon as I can. Thanks.

Comment: @user3053320 I'm glad you like my answer. If it was helpful consider upvoting an marking it as accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the score. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user3053320".

Answer (score 7):

## Remarks

The `\resume` macro takes two arguments

1. The number of points "achieved"
2. Total number of points

**EDIT:** Checks implemented. Decimal numbers will throw an error in `\ifnum`.

<s>Negative numbers will behave funny, but you might not use them anyway.
It is also not checked, if the number of points achieved is larger than the number of total points.</s>

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\resume[2]{%
  \ifnum#1>#2
    $#1 > #2$
  \else
    \ifnum#1<0
      $#1 < 0$
    \else
      \ifnum#2<0
        $#2 < 0$
      \else
        \tikz{%
        \ifx#20
        \else
          \foreach \i in {1,...,#2} {
            \filldraw[black!20] (\i ex,0) circle (0.4ex);
          };
        \fi
        \ifx#10
        \else
          \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {
            \filldraw[black] (\i ex,0) circle (0.4ex);
          };
        \fi
        }
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  Much skillz & \resume{5}{10} \\
  So recommendable & \resume{2}{10} \\
  Wow! & \resume{10}{10} \\
  10/5 & \resume{10}{5} \\
  0/0 & \resume{0}{0} \\
  0/5 & \resume{0}{5} \\
  0/-1 & \resume{0}{-1} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Can't we have 4.5/10? :)